# angular 6 time rang slider

Tags: angular

[image]

Is there any module for time range slider for following format?

Comment: for such a question: https://www.google.com/search?q=html+input+range+css+library

Answer (score 1):

You can use this

```
$scope.demo1 = {
min: 20,
max: 80
};
```

For reference: http://danielcrisp.github.io/angular-rangeslider/demo/